# Верно ли происходит удаление при создании потомков?

Tags: ооп, наследование, c++

Добрый день!
Есть родительский класс:

```
class parent{
   public:
   int g, h, j;
   ...
   void khg(){...}
   vitrual void e()=0;
   virtual ~parent(){}
}*a[1000];

class F : public parent{
  ...
  void e(){}
  ~F(){...}
}*f;
class S : public parent{
  ...
  void e(){}
  ~S(){...}
}*S;

void main(){
    f = new F[5];
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        a[i]=&f[i];
    s = new S[5];
    for(int i=5; i<10; i++)
        a[i]=&s[i-5];

    delete [] a[0];
    delete [] a[5];
}
```

Вопрос то в чем, верно ли я поступаю если хочу создать кучу обьектов разных классов, а затем вызывать у них метод e() в fore-е? Верно ли я их удаляю? Где-то есть ошибка( Программа у меня большая, сомневаюсь уже во всем(...

Comment: @Alerr  приведите ваш код в порядок, он кишит ошибками. Добейтесь хотя бы того, чтобы он компилировался. Вы же не предлагаете сделать это за вас?

Comment: просто в Вашем коде куча "дивных вещей" - иначе я их не могу назвать.

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        a=&f[i];

a - это вообще то массив. Делая подобный код, в a остается только пятый (с индексом 4) элемент.  То есть, по факту, там просто 

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        a[0] = &f[i];

Аналогично и с вторым куском.

А вот 

    delete [] a[0];
    delete [] a[5];

Это вообще жуть. Я даже не уверен, что оно компилируется.

В целом, если бы написали подобное в промышленном коде - Выгнали сразу. 

Во вторых - перепишите пример так, что бы он хотя бы компилировался.

Comment: Ой, на самом деле сильно ошибся. Исправил, в реальном коде именно как так вы написали. Теперь что можете сказать? Идея верна? Должно всё удалиться?

Comment: Формально тут вроде все в порядке.

Comment: Ок, если всё в порядке, то я не могу понять почему на компе такое удаление проходит успешно, а на мобильном устройстве(там код тоже на с++) прога вылетает. O_o Это просто мега загадка для меня(

Comment: я думаю, что строка

    delete [] a[5];

в данном случае  - UB. Потому как предыдущая все почистит.

Плюс, в любом случае, там будет ещё 990 элементов, которые будут дважды удалены, но не разу ни инициализированы. А это уже точно UB.

среда не следит за тем, что Вы заполнили первые пять элементов, потом ещё пять. оператор `delete[]` об этом ничего не знает. Абсолютно.

> Формально тут вроде все в порядке.

Формально - тут полная каша.

Comment: для начала нужно посмотреть, как работает `delete[]` внутри. А он работает по разному, в зависимости от компилятора. Не буду углубляться в подробности, но `delete[]` должен удалять массив и получает ссылку на него. А по ссылке в коде ему подсовывают не динамически созданный массив. Студия в отладочном режиме скорее всего такое переварит, хотя и ругнется. А gcc скорее всего порушит память.


`delete[]` должен вызываться для того же адреса, для которого отработал `new[]`. в коде выше элементы массива хотя и были выделены с помощью `new[]`, но удаляются странным неправильным образом.

Comment: А как быть если нужно сделать нечто подобное что я пытаюсь сгородить? Можете помочь с решением?

Comment: я подозреваю, что Вам нужен std::vector или std::list.

Comment: А тип вектора то какой? так: vector<parent> vec; vec.push_back(new child(...)); А удалять через pop()? Pop почистит всю память сам???

Comment: @KoVadim, вроде вы не правы, тут

       a[0] == static_cast<parent*>(&f[0]) == static_cast<parent*>(f) == static_cast<parent*>(new F[5])

Наверное проблема в том, что delete[] нужно применять к указателю того же типа, что был выделен new[] (точно не знаю, так ли это). Тогда получается, что правильно будет так:
       
       delete [] static_cast<F*>(a[0]);
       delete [] static_cast<S*>(a[5]);

**UPD**: по стандарту `operator delete[]` принимает `(void*)`, поэтому ему должно быть пофиг на тип указателя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> А тип вектора то какой? так:
> vector<parent> vec; vec.push_back(new
> child(...)); А удалять через pop()?
> Pop почистит всю память сам???

[[@Alerr](/users/3147/alerr)](/users/3147/alerr), можно использовать `vector<parent*>`:

```
   std::vector<parent*> a;
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
     a.push_back(new F);
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
     a.push_back(new S);
   ...
   for (parent* p: a)
     delete p;
```

или даже `unique_ptr<parent>`:

```
   std::vector<std::unique_ptr<parent>> a;
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
     a.emplace_back(new F);
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
     a.emplace_back(new S);
   ...
   // Удалять ничего не надо.
```

Создание элементов по-одному конечно будет помедленнее, чем создание массива, но если вы не создаете их миллионами, то разница будет почти не заметна.

Хотя повторюсь, у вас вроде бы все корректно написано. Может быть проблема где-то в другом месте. 
**UPD**: понял, что не так. Проблема в строчках:

```
    for(int i=5; i<10; i++)
      a[i]=&s[i];
```

Вы копируете элементы из `s` начиная с 5-го, а надо с нулевого:

```
    for(int i=5; i<10; i++)
      a[i]=&s[i - 5];
```

Comment: Да нет, это я тут на форуме криво код написал, в проге именно так: a[i]=&s[i - 5]; Спасибо за помощь с vector!